# How to lock a file with C#?

Tags: c#, io

I'm not sure what people usually mean by "lock" a file, but what I want is to do that thing to a file that will produce a "The specified file is in use" error message when I try to open it with another application.

I want to do this to test my application to see how it behaves when I try to open a file that is on this state. I tried this:

```
FileStream fs = null;

private void lockToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Juan Luis\Desktop\corte.txt", FileMode.Open);
}

private void unlockToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fs.Close();
}
```

But apparently it didn't do what I expected because I was able to open the file with Notepad while it was "locked". So how can I lock a file so it cannot be opened with another application for my testing purposes?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.71).aspx

```
FileStream s2 = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
```

Comment: Note : opening a FileStream on a file works perfectly as a lock in Windows, but does not appear to have any effect in Linux.

Answer (score 64):

You need to pass in a [`FileShare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) enumeration value of `None` to open on the [`FileStream` constructor overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.filestream.aspx):

```
fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Juan Luis\Desktop\corte.txt", FileMode.Open, 
    FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
```

Comment: Wish I can sometimes accept both answers as they are pretty much exactly the same. Hope you don't mind I'm accepting the other guy because of his lower score :)

Answer (score 9):

While FileShare.None is undoubtedly a quick and easy solution for locking a whole file you could lock part of a file using [FileStream.Lock()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public virtual void Lock(
    long position,
    long length
)

Parameters

position
    Type: System.Int64
    The beginning of the range to lock. The value of this parameter must be equal to or greater than zero (0). 

length
    Type: System.Int64
    The range to be locked.
```

and conversely you could use the following to unlock a file: [FileStream.Unlock()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.unlock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public virtual void Unlock(
    long position,
    long length
)

Parameters

position
    Type: System.Int64
    The beginning of the range to unlock. 

length
    Type: System.Int64
    The range to be unlocked.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to lock a file i.e. disallow file sharing. Each makes sense in a specific scenario.

1. Use the static `File.Open` (or any other opening method of the static `File` API) and pass in `FileShare.None`.
   It's important to understand that once the using scope is left i.e. the `FileStream` was disposed the file lock is released:

   ```
   await using FileStream lockedFile = File.Open(
     "test.txt", 
     FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
     FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
     FileShare.None);
   ```
2. Use the `FileStream` constructor and pass in `FileShare.None`.
   It's important to understand that once the using scope is left i.e. the `FileStream` was disposed the file lock is released:

   ```
   await using FileStream lockedFile = File.Open(
     "test.txt", 
     FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
     FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
     FileShare.None);
   ```
3. If you need a more control over the file lock, use `FileStream.Lock` to acquire a file lock. `FileStream.Lock` requires a position in the stream and the length as an argument to specify the locked content. This adds more flexibility as we can lock the complete file or only a part or parts of the file (partial file lock).

   Generally, use `FileStream.Unlock` to explicitly release the lock from the file or a part of the file. This member is useful to implement a temporary lock without having to dispose the current `FileStream`.

   ```
   await using var fileStream = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open);

   // Lock the first 1024 Bytes of the file
   fileStream.Lock(0, 1024);

   // Lock the last 1024 Bytes of the file
   fileStream.Lock(fileStream.Length - 1024, 1024);

   // Release the lock for the first 1024 Bytes 
   // but keep the lock for the last 1024 Bytes 
   fileStream.Unlock(0, 1024);

   // Lock the complete file
   fileStream.Lock(0, fileStream.Length);

   // Unlock the complete file
   fileStream.Unlock(0, fileStream.Length);
   ```

Answer (score -2):

I've needed this frequently enough to add this to my `$PROFILE` to use from `PowerShell`:

```
function Lock-File {
    Param( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$FileName
    )

    # Open the file in read only mode, without sharing (I.e., locked as requested)
    $file = [System.IO.File]::Open($FileName, 'Open', 'Read', 'None')

    # Wait in the above (file locked) state until the user presses a key
    Read-Host "Press Return to continue"

    # Close the file (This releases the current handle and unlocks the file)
    $file.Close()
}
```