# Can I lock a file before invoking File.Copy()

Tags: c#

I want to copy files from one directory to another with overwriting. For the sake of consistency I want to lock all destination files before copying, overwrite them, then unlock.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522232/) suggests using a `FileStream` for locking. However, both `FileStream.Lock()` or `FileShare.None` locks files from this process as well, making `File.Copy()` throw an `IOException`.

Here's a MVCE:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace Test1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var oldDir = @"c:\old\";
            var newDir = @"c:\new\";

            var locks = new List<FileStream>();
            foreach (var item in Directory.EnumerateFiles(newDir))
            {
                var newLock = new FileStream(item, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
                locks.Add(newLock);
            }

            foreach (var item in Directory.EnumerateFiles(oldDir))
            {
                var dest = Path.Combine(newDir, Path.GetFileName(item));
                File.Copy(item, dest, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is using the same `FileStream` for copying the only way, or can I still use `File.Copy()`? How?

Comment: As you already have a FileStream, you could write the copy yourself using the filestream instead of using the File.Copy.

Comment: @Vijay that I was talking about - "Is using the same FileStream for copying the only way"

Comment: Use `FileShare.Read` instead.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `FileShare.Read` has the same effect