# How do you lock a file in C# without making it unwritable after first being read?

Tags: c#, json, multithreading, locking, filestream

This question stems from this other thread: [How to lock a file with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522232/how-to-lock-a-file-with-c)

Basically let's say you want to lock a JSON file, read it, then write to it afterward, and finally unlock it.  You can lock the file using the answers from the other question.

However I'm having trouble where this is allowing me to read the file, but not write to it afterward without first unlocking the file.  That is, *the recommended method, which seems to be fairly well-respected, is locking the **same** thread out of its own resource*.

Example:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(GetJsonPath(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite,
        FileShare.None))
{
    SomeDtoType dto;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        dto = ((SomeDtoType)(new JsonSerializer()).Deserialize(reader,
                typeof(SomeDtoType)));
    }

    // Make changes to the DTO.....

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        new JsonSerializer().Serialize(writer, dto);
    }
}
```

The `using` line that creates the `StreamWriter` throws the following exception:

> Stream was not writable.

Now one thing that comes to mind is the value of `FileShare.None`.  The problem here is that that particular enum is evidently setting lock permissions for more than just external processes.

*How can you lock external threads/processes out of changing/deleting the file, yet allow your own to make these two subsequent read/write accesses?*

**EDIT:**

Evidently moving everything into the `using` block for the `StreamReader`, then setting `fs.Position` to `0` between the read and the write kind of fixes the issue.  The `fs.Position` part is fine, but having to move the write logic into the `using` block for the `StreamReader`, just so they can both use the same `FileStream` lock, seems a tad odd...

Comment: Should work fine when you stop closing stream by disposing reader... (you'd need to seek stream back obviously)

Comment: @Panzercrisis if you move a `Position` and new content is smaller than existing, then you might get a malformed content as moving a position does not reset the content.

Comment: There is special constructor for you that does not close stream - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Boolean_System_Int32_System_Boolean_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StreamReader` closes the stream if you don't use ctor overload and instruct it don't do that:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8, true, 4096, leaveOpen:true))
```

There is no finalizer in [StreamReader](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs), you can move it out `using` block and keep as undisposed, however I'd recommend explicitly control the lifetime and behavior.

Another issue is that you'll append to the file. If you want to override a content you need to reset it before you write to it:

```
fs.SetLength(0);
```