# How do I enumerate an IEnumerable a second time?

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable

I have the following:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines // passed into method

foreach (var data in lines.ParseAsEnumberable(Delimiter, StringQualifer))
{
...
}
```

This is fine for this particular `foreach` loop. But I want to go through the `lines` *again*, but get a

> "possible multiple enumeration"

*warning* if I use a similar loop *again*, and sure enough, the second time there are no enumeration results.

How do I go through the `lines` a second time?

Edited to add: I have been informed by my boss that we should not use ToList, as we have files with many gigabytes of data. What can I use instead?

Comment: Materialize the `IEnumerable<T>`, turn it into array, list etc. collection: `var list = lines.ParseAsEnumberable(Delimiter, StringQualifer).ToList()` and then loop over `list`

Comment: My boss said we should not use ToList, as we have files with many gigabytes of data. What should I use instead?

Comment: I see; since the main problem is potential inconsistency you can try doing all the tasks within single `foreach` (which is preferred way out: enumerating *multigigabyte* files *several times* is not a good idea) or lock the file (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522232/how-to-lock-a-file-with-c) to prevent anyone to modified and then loop as many times as you have to do and *supress* with `pragma`: `#pragma warning disable CA1851...#pragma warning restore CA1851` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1851)

Answer (score 6):

The problem with `IEnumerable<T>` that is in *general case* it is not *consistent*, e.g. when we read from *outer* source (like file, RDBMS table, COM port etc.)

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = File
  .ReadLines(@"c:\...")
  ...
```

we can have *different* data when we enumerate `lines` second time (file, table can be changed).
To avoid this possible inconsistency you can *materialize* the enumeration:

```
// Materialization can be required, but 
// let's avoid overhead if lines is already a collection.
// From now on source is a collection; it doesn't change between loops
var source = lines as IReadOnlyCollection<string> ?? lines.ToList();

...

// 1st loop
foreach(var data in source.ParseAsEnumberable(Delimiter, StringQualifer)) {
  ...
}

...

// 2nd loop over the very same collection
foreach(var item in source) {
  ...
}
```

**Edit:** if you absolutely sure that you have to loop over enumeration several times and you are not going to have problems with *inconsistency*, you can [suppress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1851) the warning with a help of `pragma`:

```
//TODO: Provide justification why it is safe to break the rule here
// E.g. "The file is locked and can't be modified"
#pragma warning disable CA1851

foreach (var data in lines.ParseAsEnumberable(Delimiter, StringQualifer)) {
  ...
}

...

foreach (var item in lines) {
  ...
}

// Don't forget to restore: 
// we've adjusted just one exception from the general rule 
#pragma warning restore CA1851
```

Comment: Is it possible to clone my IEnumerable? I could then enumerate each as necessary.

Comment: @Scott: shallow copy doesn't help, and deep copy is equal to materialization.